# Strange Solr values

Tags: solr

I have the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(ancestor_tag_id ORDER BY level_index SEPARATOR ' ') AS CHAR) AS hierarchy....
```

which returns the following result for hierarchy: 2 3 4

The query is specified in the database import file for solr. Consequentlywhen I look at the value of the field in Solr it is stored as: [B@7d5508

Can anyone tell me why this is happening the field itself is defined as follows:

```
<fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving an number in an textfield. That means, your numbers are processed as phrases (or terms).
Solr is using hashes to store (index) those "phrases".

Comment: But the numbers are converted to string as you can see in the SQL statement

Comment: i see. Is it not possible to avoid this conversation from numbers to strings?

Comment: Hi really sorry it seems I'd only applied this to the delta query and was not casting the full import query just me being stupid!